# Mysterious White spaces around a block element

Tags: html, css

Why are there white spaces around the yellow block element? (Tested on Chrome and Firefox: [image])

I already set margin to be zero.

I know I can easily hide them by setting the background-color of the body element.

```css
.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    width:20%;
    background-color: green;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.main{
    margin:0;
    margin-left:20%;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="main"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<body>` element has a default margin. You can get rid of it with `body{margin:0}`. Since the sidebar div is position fixed it just looks like it's not affected.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.main {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 2em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="main">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```